# how would you hyphenate apostrophed and already hyphenated words

Tags: tags, apostrophe

What would the convention for converting a hyphenated names for example would john-michael just become #john-michael?

Or names with apostrophes, would O'Leary become #o-leary?

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you. I would keep the hyphen and apostrophes. #john-michael and #l'oreal
You can check out tumblr.com .. they have a really nice tag system for posts.